# android listview update list when scrolling past the top

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'm wondering how to achieve the nice scroll past top functionality, that then updates the contents of the listview.

Do I have to do a custom ListView or is there some kind of built-in functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality out of the box on Android. However there are some implementations of the "Pull to Refresh" feature on Internet. You can try code from Chris Banes: 
[Pull To Refresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)